# Does $S^1 \times S^2$ nontrivially covers itself?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am not sure how to show whether or not $S^1 \times S^2$ nontrivially covers itself. Some help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Hint: $S^1$ nontrivially covers itself.

Comment: try writing out the definition of that operation =)

Answer (score 6):

When you started your study of covering spaces, you probably saw that
$$p_n: S^1 \longrightarrow S^1,$$
$$z \mapsto z^n$$
is a covering map for all $n \in \Bbb N$ (if not, you should check this yourself now). Of course, when $n > 1$ this is a nontrivial covering.

We can combine the above covering map $p_n$ with the trivial covering $\mathrm{Id}_{S^2}: S^2 \longrightarrow S^2$ to get a nontrivial covering
$$p_n \times \mathrm{Id}_{S^2}: S^1 \times S^2 \longrightarrow S^1 \times S^2,$$
$$(z, x) \mapsto (p_n(z), x)$$
for each $n > 1$.

Note that this works more generally: If $X$ is any topological space, then
$$p_n \times \mathrm{Id}_{X}: S^1 \times X \longrightarrow S^1 \times X,$$
$$(z, x) \mapsto (p_n(z), x)$$
is a nontrivial covering map for each $n > 1$.